# Gmail reports Stack Overflow feed as phishing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, email, rss, phishing

I am subscribed to the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag and get emails about new questions tagged JavaScript. For some reason, Gmail reports one email containing my feed as phishing.

Is this Gmail's false positive, or am I being spammed by a fake sender?

Or is something wrong with Stack Overflow's email feed?

[image: Screenshot of email]

Comment: Probably due to some of the *code* depicted in that email.

Comment: All the javascript.

Comment: tbh I just have a problem with email servers for this entirely, it lets through clear fake phishing scams like Bingo etc then my Payslip goes through to Junk mail, yes it knows what I like to see.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It occasionally fires a warning because of the content of the *code* that shows in the email (even though it's prepared HTML, not raw code, not sure what they're even picking up on there). It's prone to happen more frequently with JavaScript than, say, Haskell.

Nothing to worry about :)

Comment: That's quite bizarre. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't give any alarms? https://postmaster.google.com/managedomains?pli=1

Comment: Haskell isn't reality.

Comment: Maybe related to self-XSS? "Paste this code in the box that you see when you press Control + Shift + J, enter and you will get $1000!"

Comment: Getting JS in your SO feed? You should totally drop that and try Haskell.

Comment: @programmer5000 That's actually .. a pretty reasonable guess. I can't think of any other reason to parse prepared HTML as code. Tempted to try images of it to see if they warn on that too.

Comment: @TimPost images are less of a threat, because very few people will type malicious code in their developer console, especially if it contains a lot of symbols and is somewhat long. A link to a pastebin of the XSS code wouldn't get caught, though.